# VoiceOver on unordered list elements explicitly saying 'bullet'

Tags: html, accessibility, voiceover, screen-readers

I have a page I'm recreating with a modern build tool and am having some issues with VoiceOver on list elements.

On the production site for example when I hit a block like this

```
<ul>
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two></li>
  <li>Three</li>
</ul>
```

the screen reader reads, 'One', 'Two', 'Three' as I move through the list.  After migrating to the new build tool when I hit this block it reads 'bullet One', 'bullet Two', 'bullet Three'.

I am being asked to have VoiceOver not explicitly say 'bullet' when going through the list.  Any thoughts?  I was thinking setting 'list-style-type: none' then add a ::before each `<li>` with a content of a bullet, but the production site doesn't seem to be doing anything like that. Could this be a CSS issue?

Comment: What do you mean by modern build tool? If the **generated / served** HTML and CSS have not changed (i.e. browser DOM not your source code) then the only real thing that is likely to cause this is that your build tool is generating some styles in the shadow DOM, if you can provide an example of each behaviour we can help you track this down (either a couple of fiddles or a link to a page / couple of pages we can check).

Comment: That's the thing.  The HTML and CSS look the exact same.  I'm not even sure how I'd recreate this.

Comment: what did you change as modern build tool is a little vague

Comment: I mean I'm migrating a site from a basic html page to utilizing handlebars and gulp.  What is generating the HTML is not really relevant as far as I can tell for this issue.  The markup being loaded by the browser is the same.

Comment: No you are right, unless there is a particular flavour of handlebars that is adding something unexpected (highly unlikely). Can you make a live version of the old and new page so I can see the behaviour as at the moment I am just guessing blindly

Comment: You say, " The markup being loaded by the browser is the same." I assume this refers what the server sends, but you also mention handlebars and gulp, so it is important to check the DOM instead of simply doing "view source" in the browser. Does the DOM for the list, for whatever reason, look different from the source code?

Comment: Not at all.  The built HTML matches exactly.

Comment: Any luck? If you are still struggling do you have a sample URL for this bud? The only way a list is going to say 'bullet' is if it is unstyled / styled as a bullet list (which I am assuming it is not). Drop a link to the generated page I will spot the issue within a minute.